# DynamoDB: Importing Big Data with Python

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

We are importing a 5Gb csv file into AWS DynamoDB.
At this time, we want to finish the import into DynamoDB within an hour or two, using only Python.
Also, since we are considering concurrent processing, we cannot split the file.

Using the article below as a reference, I imported a 5Gb file and it took me 6 hours to complete.
Is there any way to make this import faster by coding Python?
I don't know much about big data, but I'd like to know more about it.

https://github.com/aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb

```
import json
import boto3
import os
import csv
import codecs
import sys

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

bucket = os.environ['bucket'].
key = os.environ['key'].
tableName = os.environ['table'].

def lambda_handler(event, context):

get() does not store in memory
try:
Object(bucket, key).get()['Body'] obj = s3.
except:
Object(bucket, key).get()['Body'] except: print("S3 Object could not be opened. Check environment variable. ")
Try:
Table(tableName)
except:
Check if table was created correctly and environment variable.") try: table = dynamodb.Table(tableName) except: print("Error loading DynamoDB table.

batch_size = 100
batch = [].

DictReader is a generator; not stored in memory
for row in csv.DictReader(codecs.getreader('utf-8')(obj)):
if len(batch) >= batch_size:
write_to_dynamo(batch)
batch.clear()

batch.append(row)

if batch:
write_to_dynamo(batch)

return {
'statusCode': 200,
'body': json.dumps('Uploaded to DynamoDB Table')
}

def write_to_dynamo(rows):
try:
table = dynamodb.Table(tableName)
except:
print("Error loading DynamoDB table. Check if table was created correctly and environment variable.")

try:
Check if table was created correctly and environment variable.") try: with table.batch_writer() as batch:
for i in range(len(rows)):
batch.put_item(
Item=rows[i])
)
except:
print("Error executing batch_writer")
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to format your code? Seems like the white space got lost, for example. I can't quite make sense of what table.batch_writer is, and I can't really see any code here that writes to dynamo? write_to_dynamo takes "rows" but you call put_item on "batch" which is a global array?

Comment: https://github.com/aws-samples/csv-to-dynamodb

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @user37263 it would be nice if you could edit your code sample right here to show what problem you're encountering. Most of us busy internet users don't have the time to go reading all the code in that aws-samples repo :)

Comment: Another thing is, what capacity mode are you running the DynamoDB table in? I recommend you pre-warm your table by creating it (faster) or changing it to do at least 10,000 writes/sec (maybe more) in provisioned capacity mode, then switch to on-demand capacity mode, then run the data load. Otherwise the table will spend a lot of time splitting partitions as you are doing the data load.

Answer (score 0):

For importing huge datasets into DynamoDB you should better use built-in [DynamoDB import from S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.HowItWorks.html) functionality. Using it, you *do not* pay for each `PutItem` request but for the amount of imported data only.

Keep in mind: **when importing to DynamoDB, you pay based on an *uncompressed* data size**. You may compress the data on S3 to reduce the transfer time and costs (if transferring to another region), but it will not affect the DynamoDB *import* operation cost.

You should prepare your data in one of [3 available formats in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/S3DataImport.Format.html):

- CSV — the simplest and the most cost-efficient, works best if you have strings-only attributes;
- DynamoDB JSON — supports all DynamoDB types (numbers, lists, etc.), requires no 3rd-party libs, works best if you have not only strings;
- Amazon Ion — supports all DynamoDB types, but you'll probably require using a 3rd-party library to reformat your data into Ion.

  - Frankly speaking, I have not found any Ion advantages compared to JSON for this use case: it is a superset of JSON and the same explicit, so no storage or compression benefits.

When using JSON, the only ways to reduce the uncompressed data size are to:

- Minimize attributes names (in JSON you have to include attributes names into every line).
- Use dictionary compression for attributes values, i.e. if you have a enum field, store its values as `1`, `2`, `3`, for example, and then decode them in your application code when reading from DynamoDB: `{1: 'val1', 2: 'val2', …}.get(dynamodb_field_value)`.
- Drop all unnecessary symbols, i.e. whitespaces.

If you have strings only, I highly recommend you to use the CSV format since you do not have to include fields names into every line in that case.